# What is really the difference between underscore _.each and _.map?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using UnderscoreJs. Consider this code:

```
var docs = [
    {name : 'Anders', niche : 'Web Development'}, 
    {name : 'Johnny', niche : 'Design'}, 
    {name : 'Eric', niche : 'PhotoShop'}
];

var newDocs = _.map(docs, function (doc){
    delete doc.niche;
    return doc;
});
```

It doesn't matter if I use `.each` or `.map` here. The outcome is exactly the same.

What is really the difference between the two in the case above?

Comment: what library, underscore?

Comment: Read [the manpage](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-13), it's not that hard to look it up.

Comment: `_.each()` *iterates*, `_.map()` *projects*, i.e. builds a new array from the one passed as input, using the function you specify to build the new elements.

Comment: One iterates, one collects? You have a pathological case where you're running it for side effects.

Comment: How it is intended to be used: `var newDocs = _.map(docs, function (doc){ return doc.name; });`

Comment: @epascarello: Thanks! I had not thought about that!...

Comment: I upvoted to balance the downvote, I think it is a good question for whose are not ok with the map function. Just look at the number of responses... and the great quality of two of them.

Comment: @Rémi - good job. You gotta love answers like "read the documentation" - that's really helpful to a beginner. Just another instance of arrogant comments from folks who feel they are elite, and choose to bash questions they feel are beneath them. I wish they would answer with "read the documentation" so I could downvote it into the stone age. I'd rather they just stay off the site. Also see [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users).

Comment: @Nit - sorry man. That documentation you cited may be correct, but its useless to someone without familiarity. I can only say "may be" because it makes no sense to me. Great job with helping someone less familiar with the technology than you.

Comment: @jww ... Yes, I think that reading the doc is an important thing to do. And also answer the question. No arogance. Really.

Comment: Of course I have read the docs. But I did not fully understand the difference. I wanted an explanation in human readable form, which  StriplingWarrior so pedagogically provided below!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`map` is intended to be a functional mapping method: its function argument should return a value, but *is not expected to have any side-effects*.

`each` is just a functional replacement for an imperative `for` loop: its purpose is to have an effect, and it *is not expected to return any value*.

For example, this would be a more appropriate use for `map`:

```
var docs = getDocs();
var docTitles = _.map(docs, function (doc){
    return doc.title;
});
// expect `docs` to be unchanged
```

Whereas this would be an appropriate use for `each`:

```
var docs = getDocs();
_.each(docs, function (doc){
    delete doc.niche;
});
// expect `docs` to be altered.
```

Answer (score 8):

## _.each(list, iteratee)

> Iterates over a list of elements, yielding each in turn to an iteratee function.
>
> *Each invocation of iteratee is called with three arguments: (element, index, list). If list is a JavaScript object, iteratee's arguments will be (value, key, list). Returns the list for chaining.*

```
_.each({one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}, alert);
=> alerts each number value in turn...
```

## _.map(list, iteratee)

> Produces a new array of values by mapping each value in list through a transformation function (iteratee).
>
> *If list is a JavaScript object, iteratee's arguments will be (value, key, list).*

```
_.map({one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}, function(num, key){ return num * 3; });
=> [3, 6, 9]
```

see [documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#collections)

Answer (score 4):

Your assertion that the results are "exactly the same" is untrue. The `_.each()` function returns the *original* list, but `_.map()` returns a *new* list. You're directly modifying the original objects as you go, so you end up with references to the same objects in each list, but with `_.map()` you end up with two separate array instances.

Answer (score 4):

You can just look at the source code to see the difference:

- [`_.each`](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-16):

  ```
  _.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iteratee, context) {
      if (obj == null) return obj;
      iteratee = createCallback(iteratee, context);
      var i, length = obj.length;
      if (length === +length) {
        for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          iteratee(obj[i], i, obj);
        }
      } else {
        var keys = _.keys(obj);
        for (i = 0, length = keys.length; i < length; i++) {
          iteratee(obj[keys[i]], keys[i], obj);
        }
      }
      return obj;
  };
  ```
- [`_.map`](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-17):

  ```
  _.map = _.collect = function(obj, iteratee, context) {
      if (obj == null) return [];
      iteratee = _.iteratee(iteratee, context);
      var keys = obj.length !== +obj.length && _.keys(obj),
          length = (keys || obj).length,
          results = Array(length),
          currentKey;
      for (var index = 0; index < length; index++) {
        currentKey = keys ? keys[index] : index;
        results[index] = iteratee(obj[currentKey], currentKey, obj);
      }
      return results;
  };
  ```